# Oracle 12g - DB services no longer available

Tags: oracle

For some reason the Oracle services for my 12.1.0.4 database running on Linux 6 are no longer responding. When I run:

```
srvctl status service -d <DBNAME>
```

nothing gets returned. No error. No msg of any kind.
When I try to start or stop the services it's the same:

```
srvctl start service -d <DBNAME>
srvctl stop service -d <DBNAME>
```

The other DBs on that same host look ok. And this was working previously. Any ideas what could have happened? And how can I resolve this?

Many thanks

Comment: have you tried `srvctl status database -d <DBNAME>` ?

Comment: Yes. That works - Instance <INSTNAME> is running on node <host>

Comment: Configured as expected? srvctl config db -d <DB_UNIQUE_NAME>, as always, the alert log will always tell you the truth.

Comment: yeah the 'Services: ' line is blank. Everything else looks good.

Answer (score 0):

In a situation like this the service needs to be (re)created/added using the command: srvctl add service -db db_unique_name -service service_name
Then started: srvctl start service -d DBNAME